# how can i Thread and play sound while program still working and noe freezing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to play a sound but my program is freezing while doing that and after some reading about "Threading" I have tried this and it printed back this error:

> AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'warning'

I have tried this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import winsound
import time
from threading import *

class A(Thread):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(513, 174)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Play_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Play_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 70, 321, 63))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Play_but.setFont(font)
        self.Play_but.setObjectName("Play_but")
        self.security = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.security.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 10, 187, 32))
        self.security.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.security.setFont(font)
        self.security.setObjectName("security")
        self.warning = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.warning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 199, 37))
        self.warning.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.warning.setFont(font)
        self.warning.setObjectName("warning")
        self.notAllowed = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.notAllowed.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 10, 199, 32))
        self.notAllowed.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(211, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.notAllowed.setFont(font)
        self.notAllowed.setObjectName("notAllowed")
        self.minute = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.minute.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.minute.setFont(font)
        self.minute.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.minute.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.minute.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.minute.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.UpDownArrows)
        self.minute.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.minute.setObjectName("minute")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 196, 24))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 513, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.Play_but.clicked.connect(play)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "messageTest"))
        self.Play_but.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Play"))
        self.security.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "sound 2"))
        self.warning.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "sound 1"))
        self.notAllowed.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "sound 3"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "timming"))

    def run(self):
        warning = r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Hpk\sounds\warning.wav'

        if self.warning.isChecked():
            winsound.PlaySound(warning, winsound.SND_NOSTOP)

class B(Thread):
    def make(self):
        t1 = A()
        t1.start()


def play():
    b = B()
    b.make()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = A()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm afraid you're a bit confused on how to use threads and PyQt.

Secondly, the main reason for that error is that you're trying to get access to an instance attribute that does not exists.

That's what's going on:

1. you create `class A`; at this point, that *class* has almost no attribute except from those of the `threading.Thread` base classes and the "name" of the `setupUi` function (which has not been run yet);
2. within the `if __name__ == "__main__:"` statement you create an *instance* of `class A`, let's call it "`instanceA_1`";
3. following that, you call `setupUi()`, a [*bound* method](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) (a function that is "bound" to an instance, which is what `self` usually refers to) of `class A`, which will create and set a lot of *instance attributes* such as the `Play_but` button and the `warning` checkbox; those are attributes of the instance, **not** of the class: to the class there's no button, no warning, no nothing, except from the aforementioned `Thread` base *class attributes*; also, it's important to keep in mind that, according to your code, every `self.*` object you create there is an attribute of a `Thread` instance object;
4. after clicking the button, the *global* `play` function is started, which creates an instance of `class B` ("`instanceB_1`");
5. `instanceB_1.make()` creates a **new** instance of `A`, "`instanceA_2`" (what you call `t1`); `instanceA_1.warning` exists because you run `setupUi` against it, but `instanceA_2` will know *nothing* about any `warning` since `setupUi` has not been called (right now, `instanceA_2` has the same attributes as `instanceA_1` had up to point 2);
6. you start the *thread* of `instanceA_2`, trying to access `self.warning`, but, as explained before, the instance ("`self`") doesn't have *any* `warning` attribute, hence the error you get;

Now, logic would suggest to add another `t1.setupUi`, or find another way to keep track of the first instance in the first place.
That's not the case, as your implementation has a bigger flaw to begin with: you're trying to use a Thread as a base to create a GUI element, which is wrong from at least two points of view.

1. Qt (as most of GUI frameworks) has it own [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) thread, which should be left alone (also, no GUI elements should **ever** be accessed nor modified from any other thread);
2. You're creating GUI elements as attributes of the Thread, which doesn't make much sense, especially considering the previous point (PyQt doesn't check if a GUI element is an attribute of another thread, nor it should).

I'm afraid that you've fallen into the common mistake of reimplementing the output of the `pyuic` command: trying to understand what it does and mimic its behavior.
Unfortunately, the PyQt documentation is not very clear about that, and even the pyuic generated file itself isn't (even if the `WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!` should be a prime suspect to begin with); long story short, you should just leave those file as they are. Just read the [official documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), and use your own code to create GUI objects following it and implement your concepts from *there*.

---

Finally, the main event loop of Qt should always be left alone as much as possible; this means that you should avoid any high load process that could potentially block the interface (such as loading big files, or playing audio or video) until the process has finished.
In your case, playing the file will block everything until the sound has finished; you should add the [`winsound.SND_ASYNC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_ASYNC) flag instead, which returns immediately, avoiding any unnecessary threading from the beginning:

```
    winsound.PlaySound(warning, winsound.SND_NOSTOP | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Comment: Wow, that was a nice reflection of my skills! Thank you very much for the comment.          i hope to get better next time.

Comment: Why not avoid all these unnecessary complications and use [QSound](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html)? It plays sound files asynchronously by default (so no need for multi-threading).